# Create a clustered bar chart in Excel, group together for values with same category

Tags: excel, bar-chart

I am trying to create a clustered bar chart that puts together the values for those in the same category. So for all of Alpha I want the 4 bars to be together in quarter order, then for Beta and so on. But I am getting a bar chart that has all bars separate, and I can't seem to group if the category is the same.
My data looks like this:

```
Category    Quarter    Sales
Alpha         Q1       345
Alpha         Q2       456
Alpha         Q3       562
Alpha         Q4       389
Beta          Q1       788
Beta          Q2       867
Beta          Q3       934
Beta          Q4       980
Gamma         Q1       488
Gamma         Q2       545
Gamma         Q3       462
Gamma         Q4       389
Delta         Q1       689
Delta         Q2       892
Delta         Q3       744
Delta         Q4       956
```

This is the chart I am getting

[image: This is the Chart I am getting]

This is the kind of chart I want, except that instead of each cluster to be Qx, I want them be for each category  and each bar for the quarters 1-4.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried sorting the data by quarter?

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your data. This has been answered here [Creating a “grouped” bar chart from a table in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1099503/creating-a-grouped-bar-chart-from-a-table-in-excel)

```
         Q1 Q2  Q3  Q4
Alpha   345 456 562 389
Beta    788 867 934 980
Gamma   488 545 462 389
Delta   689 892 744 956
```

[image: chart]